# How to set line ending in git attributes for all subfolders

Tags: git, gitattributes

My git repository contains some Windows and Linux files. For example,

```
/.gitattributes
/a/b/Windows/*
/a/b/Linux/*
```

Both Windows and Linux folders contain many subfolders and many different type of extensions (e.g. source code, text fies, tarball, binaries, etc)

How can I set the gitattribute so that when I checkout the repository, all the files in Windows folder will be set to eol=crlf, and Linux folder will be set to eol=lf?

In addition, how can I test the changes without push the changes to the remote repository?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this:

```
/a/b/Windows/* text eol=crlf
/a/b/Linux/*   text eol=lf
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I test the changes without git push?

Comment: Not exactly sure.. but if it's in your config file then it should work locally without pushing it just yet. My bet is just open your checked-out files with a text editor that shows CRLFs.

Comment: Nope. I tried to test the Linux folder. I created a branch, made the changes to .gitattributes, commit the changes and switch back to master branch. And then checkout the new branch and do not see the changes of files in Linux folder to LF in text editor.

Comment: Try `git check-attr eol FILENAME` from https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Troubleshooting